# Redux Saga + Socket lags

Tags: reactjs, sockets, redux, websocket, redux-saga

I am learning Redux-Saga and faced such a problem.

I have a socket that sends me 40+ messages per second in real time.
This is written to the Store via yield put, and as I understand it, the data does not have time to be written, as new ones are already arriving - which causes terrible lags.

If you do not process all messages from the socket, then there are no lags.

Tell me how to solve this issue?

Here's a sample code if needed:

**Socket**

```
socketOnmessage (pipe) {
  const data = yield take (channel);
  
  while (true) {
    yield put ({
      type: UPDATE_TABLE,
      payload: data,
    });
}
```

**In reducer**

```
types of cases. UPDATE_TABLE:
      return [... state, {... payload}]. splice (-80);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without understanding the plumbing in terms of how the `socketOnmessage` is triggered and how things are supposed to work, but the `while (true) {` loop is almost certainly incorrect. Basically after a successful `take`, the infinite loop is started and `yield put` is called over and over as fast as possible forever without stopping which will certainly make your app lag.

At the very least the `take` should be inside the infinite loop so `put` is only called once per `take`:

```
socketOnmessage (pipe) {
  while (true) {
    const data = yield take (channel);
    yield put ({
      type: UPDATE_TABLE,
      payload: data,
    });
}
```

That said something else seems off since `socketOnmessage` should be a generator function in order to call `yield`, which it is not in your sample code.

If you still have lag after fixing that there are other options. Is it a constant stream of 40 messages per second? Perhaps implement a buffer that limits the number of state updates by filling the buffer on each event and processing all events in the buffer once every 500ms with only a single state update instead of updating state on each message.